# How to pass dynamic reference in Cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I want to send push notification for the particular users using cloud function.

Here is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendPushNotification = functions.database.ref('/Users/{id}').onWrite(event => {
const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: 'Test message',
        body: 'Hope you are fine',
        badge: '1',
        sound: 'default',
    }
};

return admin.database().ref('fcmToken').once('value').then(allToken => {
    if(allToken.val()){
        const token = Object.keys(allToken.val());
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(response => {

        });
    }
});
});
```

But, how to do it dynamically, i.e, I want to send push notification for the particular user, this code is sending the notification to all the users registered. So, help me to change the static id(db reference) to dynamic(db reference) and also how to pass different content for notification in this code lines:

```
const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: 'Test message',
        body: 'Hope you are fine',
        badge: '1',
        sound: 'default',
    }
};
```

Anyone there to guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved it dynamically. Hope it helps someone.

Here's my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendPushNotification = functions.database.ref('/Users/{id}').onWrite(event => {

var eventSnapshot = event.data;
    var particularUser = eventSnapshot.child('City');
    if (particularUser.changed()) {
      const payload = {
              notification: {
                  title: 'Test message',
                  body: 'Hope you are fine',
                  badge: '1',
                  sound: 'default',
              }
          };

          var getToken = eventSnapshot.child('fcmToken');

                  const token = Object.keys(getToken.val());
                  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload).then(response => {

                  });

    }


});
```

If to change the notification content, you can get it from database once you update from app side.